# Lossless Compression of flowing array of bytes

Tags: compression, real-time

I have to compress an array of bytes (no information about repetition) in real time. Every second I may receive 45000x80x15 bytes and I have to compress them in 1 second. And also decompress the same in 1 second. What algorithms can I follow?